# CreateDirectoyW(...) API fails with error code = 123 (

Tags: windows, sdk

I want to create directory with relatively long name ( approx. > 260 chars.), so I am using CreateDirectoryW(...) API as per MSDN documentation.
but it fails for long name directory ( > 260) ..can anybody tell me the solution???

I am using Visual Studio 2008 on Microsoft Windows 2003 Server

e.g.

```
CString s = L"\\\\?\\C:\\dir1\\dir2\\<long name > 260 char>";
bool b = CreateDirectoryW(s, NULL);
```

The actual path is:

```
CString s = L"\\?\C:\data\temp\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopq1234567890";
```

Comment: The example path you gave is properly escaped, but the actual path you gave is not.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the limit for a single path component is still 255 characters. All that the `\\?\` facility allows you to do is compose a path that is longer that 260 characters in its entirety.

From [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx):

> The Windows API has many functions that also have Unicode versions to permit an extended-length path for a maximum total path length of 32,767 characters. This type of path is composed of components separated by backslashes, each up to the value returned in the *lpMaximumComponentLength* parameter of the [GetVolumeInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364993.aspx) function (this value is commonly 255 characters).

---

Also, for reference, error 123 is defined in winerror.h as ERROR_INVALID_NAME